# Is there a way of achieving a very subtle blur effect in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering, blur

I am trying to get some proper text rendering with WPF. Everything related to this have come across on the web speak of problems regarding blurry font. So this is not a duplicate, I rather want a subtle blur to get the effect of 'smooth anti aliasing'

It seems that the Blur Effect doesn't work with very small blur radius values. I get a decent result with a value of 2:

[image: Value-2]

But with both 1(Top) and 0(Bottom), I get the same results:

[image][image]

If I try a value between 1 and 2, like 1.5, it's still the same as 0.

So my question is : Is there a way of achieving a very subtle blur effect in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ClearType for rendering, it will use blue and red subpixels to get smooth text.

```
RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. But thanks for your time